# How to use Android Buttons for controlling YouTube video playback in WebView?

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, controls

I have two buttons and a webview in a relative layout. The WebView will always load youtube.com .I want to control the youtube's video playback i.e play or pause using my own buttons instead of the inbuilt youtube play/pause buttons. Is it even possible ? do we need to use Javascript / HTML5 or it can be Done using Youtube API ? Suggest me some solution or any other alternative. 
[This is how the actual app looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDNcw.png)

Thanks a lot .

public class WebViewTube extends AppCompatActivity {

```
WebView webView;
Button play, stop ;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view_tube);

    play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playTube);
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopTube);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings  webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/");


    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // No idea What to write here
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            // No idea What to write here

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is to load an embedded youtube player in your `WebView` as described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters). Dont forget to include **enablejsapi=1**.

Then make your android buttons invoke some javascript to pause, play, whatever, using

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:playVideo()");
```

Comment: i actually want to use the entire site instead of embedding the player and setting different link. While using the YouTube site if user wishes to play or pause it should be done using android buttons. Anyways thanks for suggestions. I am looking forword to use YTSDK lets see.